# Java 8 - How to use Map.compute with Collection values

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

I have a `Map< Char , List<T> >`, to which I want to assign elements of type `T`, depending on the key.
I want to do it with Java 8 and `Map.compute` or `Map.merge`. 
If the key does not exisist in the `Map`, a new `List` with one element `T` shall be created as value, else, the element shall be added to the list.
This is what i came up with, and it looks awful and is not what i wanted regarding conciseness / readability.

```
newNodes.compute(currentChar,
          (k,v) -> { if(v==null) {
            List<Sequence> list = new ArrayList<Sequence>();
            list.add(currentSequence);
            return list;
            } else { 
              v.add(currentSequence);
              return v;
              }}
          );
```

Things I'd like to improve/know:

1) Sadly, I couldn't just hand over `List::add`, as it returns a boolean instead of `List<T>`. So I wrote these ugly methods.

2) Also, i wanted to incorporate the more readable " bool ? exp1 : exp2 "-pattern, but it somehow doesn't like to be in there. The `{...}`-blocks don't work with that. Why is that so?

3) If the key is not in the map yet, it should also just be added (I do add them in the code before). Is that possible in this part too (without hurting readability too much)?

There has to be an elegant way to do this but everything I try is either wrong or makes the mess worse. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Besides the fact that `newNodes.computeIfAbsent(currentChar, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(currentSequence);` is much easier for your use case, your function is unnecessarily complicated. Using `compute`, you could simply write: `newNodes.compute(currentChar, (k,v) -> { if(v==null) v = new ArrayList<>(); v.add(currentSequence); return v; });`, but, as said, `computeIfAbsent` is even simpler.

Comment: Regarding your third bullet, `compute` *does* add the key, if it’s not present and your function returns a non-`null` value. What did you think, how it works?

Comment: Thanks Holger and Tunaki for pointing me there, I really did not find this question. (I think I put enough work into my question to "prove" that). 

I dismissed  `computeIfAbsent` too soon, b\c i considered it to be only half the rent. The way you pointed out is very elegant imho. I love Java8 :-)

Comment: Ok, I'm officially stupid: "IfAbsent" is, of course, regarding the key. I thought about the value. I request immediate vacation.